# Silverlight 4 Unit Testing

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I've installed Silverlight 4 Toolkit April 2010 and have VS 2010 RTM but Silverlight 4 Unit Test Project template is not installed.

Is it by default for this release? If so, how can I use SL4 unit testing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:
The Silverlight 4 Toolkit installer placed the item templates and project templates for the SilverLight Unit Test
in c:/program files/microsoft visual studio 10.0/common7/ide, regardless of your actual VS2010 install root.

The upshot is that if your VS2010 installation did not use the default c:/program files/microsoft visual studio 10.0/...,
the project and item templates would be in the wrong place after the SL4 install.

The fix would be :

```
1) Copy the corresponding .zip files 
   from c:\program files\...\common7\ide\... 
   to ?your installpath?\common7\ide\...

   Silverlight Unit Test Framework has templates for CSharp and VisualBasic.

   For example :
   common7\ide\itemtemplates\CSharp\silverlight\1033\Silverlight Unit Test Class.zip
   common7\ide\projecttemplates\CSharp\silverlight\1033\Silverlight Unit Test Project.zip

2) Use the VS command prompt to install the templates with the command :
   devenv /installvstemplates
```

Now, when you open a New Project in VS2010, you should see the "Silverlight Unit Test application" in 
the ?Lang?/Silverlight tab of the "Installed Templates" section.

Hope this helps,

Comment: One common case: 64 bits OS... 'Program Files (x86)' vs 'Program Files'.

Comment: Hi... what do you mean with "Your installpath"?

Comment: "devenv /installvstemplates" was they key piece I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also installed the Silverlight 4 Tools?  This is not included in the VS 2010 RTM.

My install order:-

- VS 2010
- [Silverlight Tools 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b3deb194-ca86-4fb6-a716-b67c2604a139)
- Silverlight 4 Toolkit April 2010 (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases)

In templates I see a "Silverlight Unit Test Application"

Comment: I have installed "Microsoft Silverlight 4 Tools for Visual Studio 2010". Is this it?

Comment: Installing the "Tools" is definitely not enough to get the "Silverlight Unit Test Application" project type, you must also install the "Toolkit", which is different.